# Howto get the RedirectURL from WinRT WebView control

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to authenticate a windows 8 app via OAuth on a service. 
This works by using the WebView control and navigate the user with a proper URL to the service where the authentication takes place.

If the user is authenticated by the service, he is redirected to a success page.

I'd like to get the information about this redirect so that i can start the application automatically.

I've tried the the LoadComplete event which is fired when a page is loaded, but there i only get the request uri, but not the redirect uri.

```
webView.LoadCompleted += webView_LoadCompleted;
webView.Navigate(new Uri("service uri));
```

Has anyone an idea howto get the redirect url, or at least the page content(This i could parse and look for something like "great, you're authenticated")

Comment: Are you redirecting to http://localhost:8080 (or any other port) ? When you receive the request there, it means you are ready to go.

Answer (score 4):

There is a built in mechanism for this that is more secure for users (apps can't snoop passwords).  See web authentication broker:  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Comment: +1 Another plus side is the UI is consistent with other applications signing in to web services.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the WebView page content doing something like this:

```
private void webView_LoadCompleted_1(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    WebView webView = sender as WebView;
    string html = webView.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] {"document.documentElement.outerHTML;"});

    // Here you can parse html ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method, to redirect up to a URL and then block the further redirection.

```
WebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    var url = args.Uri.ToString();
    if(url == "")
        args.Cancel = true;
}
```